# SSL certificate (.pfx) file issue in IIS Server

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, ssl-certificate

In my app, I need to use SSL certificate of third party to perform payment operation. The certificate is is .pfx file format.

While using localhost, I had stored certificate in certificate store and it was working fine. But after deploying my app in IIS server, it has stopped working. My application is not able to locate certificate and error is coming when trying to read private key.

Should I bind .pfx file on IIS Server so that I can use it in my app? If so, how do I bind?

Comment: I guess "While using localhost" should be "while using Visual Studio", https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Lex Li I already know this and this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to bind the certificate with your site in iis. to do this you could follow the below steps:

- Click  Start, select   Run and enter MMC
- Click   File and select   Add/Remove Snap-in
- Click   Add, select   Certificates in the Standalone Snap-in list
  and click   Add

[image]

- Select   Computer Account and click   Next
- Select   Local Computer and click   Finish
- Close the window and click OK in the upper window
- Go to the Personal Certificates repertory
- Right-click on it and select All tasks > Import
- Via the wizard, search for your .pfx file
- Enter yours.pfx opening password
- check the box to "Mark this key as exportable"
- Finally, choose to automatically place the certificates in the certificate stores based on the type of the certificate.
- Click Finish
- Close the MMC

  **Bind the certificate in IIS**
- Open iis manager and select your site.
- In the Action Pane, click Bindings
- Click New
- Fill out the information in the add site binding window. In the type drop-down choose https. Set the IP address to the IP address of the site or choose all unassigned. The port for SSL traffic is usually 443. Enter the recently imported certificate in the SSL Certificate field.

[image]

- Click OK. Your SSL Certificate is now installed and the website is configured to accept secure connections. You may have to restart IIS or the server for it to recognize the new certificate.

[image]